# kotlin native cannot import khttp

Tags: ios, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-native

I'm having a problem with usage of khttp library (which is supposed to work in Kotlin and provides equal to python's request's library features)

My build.gradle contains those strings:

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
    compile "com.github.jkcclemens:khttp:-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

Project builds with success, but importing with `import khttp` doesn't work

In general, I'm using kotlin as framework to IOS project, and `khttp` is needed to connect to longpoll server. If `khttp` isn't supposed to work in my case so what are my options? Using it's sources aint good idea i think

Comment: Does khttp support iOS ? I read that in order to run native kotlin code in both iOS, android or other platforms, the libraries used in the code must support it.

Comment: @PedroGomes I was not able to make it run 6 months ago

Answer (score 4):

Try using this:

```
compile "com.github.jkcclemens:khttp:0.1.0"
```

And add https://jitpack.io/ as a repository

Answer (score 2):

I know that I might be necrobumping, but if anyone is looking for an answer, they wouldn't be able to get it from the above.

Khttp library is build for kotlin JVM and not native. If you take a look at the source code, you'll be able to notice that it's using Java's libraries for it to function, [this](https://github.com/jkcclemens/khttp/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/khttp/responses/Response.kt#L12) for example.

That means that sadly you can't run it on iOS and any platform that doesn't run JVM, as khttp will only run on the JVM platform and won't be able to run on native because of missing libraries.